# Testing Elasticsearch in Golang without sleep

Tags: testing, asynchronous, elasticsearch, go

I am really new to Golang and I have a question regarding to testing.
I had a test where I wanted to check whether the persisting of a customer in elasticsearch works or not. I've reduced the code to the critical part and posted it on github: (https://github.com/fvosberg/elastic-go-testing)

The problem is, that I have to wait for elasticsearch to index the new document, before I can search for it. Is there another option than waiting a second for this to happen? This feels very ugly, but I don't know how I can test the integration (working with elasticsearch with lowercasing the email address ...) in another way.

Are there solutions for this problem?

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/fvosberg/elastic-go-testing/customer"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestRegistration(t *testing.T) {
    testCustomer := customer.Customer{Email: "testing@test.de"}
    testCustomer.Create()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    _, err := customer.FindByEmail("testing@test.de")
    if err != nil {
        t.Logf("Error occured: %+v\n", err)
        t.Fail()
    } else {
        t.Log("Found customer testing@test.de")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch has a flush command that is useful for this situation.  Since you're using the `elastic` project as an interface, you can use the following (where client is your ES client):

`...
testCustomer.Create()
res, err := client.Flush().Do()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
_, err := customer.FindByEmail("testing@test.de")
...`

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't believe that there is a solution for this problem other than waiting for a second. It works like a charm